# Error in var #theID="quizChoice"+i.toString();

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to create four buttons where four labels appear in a random order:

```
<div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice0"></button>
            </div>
             <div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice1"></button>
            </div>
             <div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice2"></button>
            </div>
             <div class="row text-center center-block">
                <button class="quizChoice btn btn-md btn-info" id="quizChoice3"></button>
</div>
```

The labels are stored under the

`var choiceLabels = ["Hola", "Hole", "Holo", "Holu"];`

Then the code iterates through the choices to stick them in the buttons:

```
for (var i=0; i<choiceLabels; i++) {
    var #theID="quizChoice"+i.toString();
    $(theID).text(choiceLabels[i])
};
```

But I get the following error:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token** in line

`var#theID="quizChoice"+i.toString();`

Anybody know why?

Answer (score 1):

as you are trying to access element by its ID , i.e you are trying Id selector in jquery then you must append `#` before your id so in you case it will be

```
for (var i=0; i<choiceLabels; i++) {
    var theID="#quizChoice"+i.toString();
    $(theID).text(choiceLabels[i])
};
```

you dont need to put `#` in your variable that is also updated in my answer. i.e. instead of `#theID` you have to use `theID`

Answer (score 0):

You need to append `#` in the string to be a selector with id, not before the variable name. Your value must be the selector - `theID` is just a variable, which value will be evaluated in the `$()`, not it's name.

```
var theID = "#quizChoice" + i.toString();
//           ^
$(theID).text(choiceLabels[i])
```